# MySQL column into PHP array error

Tags: php, mysql, stdclass

I have a problem with getting MySQL column into php array variable , for further `foreach()` cycling.

Here is my code:

```
$files=array();
$filesFetch = "SELECT FileName FROM articledata";
$rs=mysql_query($filesFetch);
while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
$files[]=$rd->files;
}

if (!$files) {
    die('getting filenames failed');
}
foreach ($files as $key => $id) 
{  //... do the stuff }
```

I am not getting stopped at the `die` condition, but my error says:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$files

I assume there is problem with formatting, because this error notice repeats :"rowCountTimes"

Also this error appears for the line.

```
$files[]=$rd->files;
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object has properties based on the column names; you need to use:

```
$files[]=$rd->fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching FileName, so you must use that in your object:

```
$files[]=$rd->FileName;
```

Comment: Thank You , same as the guys above

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$rd->FileName
```

instead of `$rd->files` since your column name is `FileName`

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote certainly doesn't make sense. You are fetching an object which is saved in a variable `$rd`. Then you are trying to access property `files` but of course that is undefined since you only fetched the column named FileName.

So use instead:
`$files[] = $rd->FileName;`